# Accessing an array sent using JSON

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, arrays, json

I am having following array

```
 var array = []; // It has (48.154176701412744,11.551694869995117),(48.15131361676726,11.551694869995117),(48.15555092529958,11.549291610717773) saved in it.
```

And thats how I am sending it via ajax to my aspx page

```
 function result() {
     var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ list: array });
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.aspx/Demo", type: "POST", dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: jsonText,
        success: function (data) { alert("it worked"); },
        error: function () { alert("Uh oh"); }
    });
    return false;
}
```

And thats how I am accessing it in my aspx

```
public static void Demo(double[] list)
{

}
```

But when I try to print it, it gives me "0 0 0". And when I try to access it like

```
public static void Demo(string[] list)
{

}
```

The above method doesn't even accepts JSON object. So, what should the appropriate data type be used to access this array as the method doesn't even accept the JSON object?  Or tell me the way to split string like (xyz,xyz),(xyz,xyz) in JS, so that  I can convert it into string and sent it with JSON as a string?

Comment: It doesn't work this way.

Comment: does your method has the attribute `[WebMethod]`?

Comment: Yup!! in fact, it works when I send it plain string. Thats why I made splitting string part of my question.

Comment: If you look at your JavaScript array, it doesn't contain ints or strings. A value of xx.xxxxxxxxxx is rather a decimal, but seeing as each object in your array contains TWO values, I'm guessing you need to accept a complex type as parameter.

Comment: Could you possibly do a console.log in your code before stringifying it so we can see what the array looks like?

Comment: @FarligOpptreden, actually I am making array onclick event on a google map and it keep all the google coordinates in it. Lets say I have clicked on three different locations then my array would be like "(48.154176701412744,11.551694869995117),(48.15131361676726,11.551694869995117),(48.15555092529958,11.549291610717773)". And thats how my array looks like before I stringify it.

Comment: I assumed those are coordinates. The problem is that (xxx,yyy) is not an object in JavaScript. [xxx,yyy] would be a perfectly valid object (an array with 2 items), even {x: xxx, y: yyy} would be a valid object, but (xxx,yyy) isn't. I would appreciate it if you can just do a console.log and provide us with the output so we can see the structure of the array...

Comment: THats what comes in my browser's console     Array[3]
0: O
1: O
2: O
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be the parameter that you are accepting for your web method is of incorrect type. Change the parameter type for your web method to `List<Dictionary<string,string>>`, that way most objects would be deserialized correctly, especially if it is a JSON type like in your example.

Having no experience in the Google maps API yet, a quick search revealed that it might look something along these lines:

```
var coord = { "lat" : "xx.xxxxxxx", "long" : "yy.yyyyyyyy" };
```

If that is indeed the case, a parameter of type `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` would correctly deserialize the JSON array you are passing through the AJAX call.

Below is a sample of how to loop through the list provided to your web method and build a string of all the coordinates:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> coord in list)
{
    sb.Append(string.Format("({0},{1})", coord["lat"], coord["long"]));
}
```

You can, of course, change the format in which the string is built up to suit your requirements. Again, the assumption is that the dictionary gets deserialized with keys for "lat" and "long", of which I'm not sure. Hope it helps!

Comment: Perfect, it works. But now how can I convert this into a string so that I can save it into my database column?

Comment: You can just concatenate the values in the dictionary to a single string, separated by commas. So just loop through each item in the dictionary, get the value from it and then use a StringBuilder to build up the string. If you're happy with my answer, please accept it.

Comment: If you can kindly give a coding example of that as I am not good at splitting string and stuff.

Comment: I guess the dude below :/ not sure

Comment: bro even List<Dictionary<string,string>> this doesn't give me the same values as "0 0 0".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean? Does it give the results "0" for each coordinate when you concatenate the string? Would you mind sharing some more details in the OP and, if you can, a network trace dump? Run the developer tools of Chrome (F12), go to the "Network" tab and interrogate the AJAX call that happens to your web method. Specifically have a look at the headers that get sent through and post those in the OP.

Comment: I have done it. Its something related to latLng method in GMaps. I converted the values to string and saved them in an array and sent it using JSON. Now, its working as I was expecting. Anyway, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

change your array with this

```
var array = [[48.154176701412744,11.551694869995117],[48.15131361676726,11.551694869995117],[48.15555092529958,11.549291610717773]];
```

hope this will help

Comment: The "text" thing suggested by you doesn't work. Tell me the alternate of JSON.stringify according to my requirement, Thanks.

Comment: It's not necessary. ASP.NET should deserialize the string to the correct type, but you have to accept the correct type as parameter for your web method first.

Comment: @ejazdogar check my updated answer hope this will work

Comment: @JeetendraChauhan, bro this way it doesn't even send the JSON object and I am only getting a page refresh.

Comment: Your answer changed COMPLETELY, so the comments aren't relevant anymore. Please mention any such drastic changes in your answer in the future as it is confusing reading the comments now.